# How can I write diagonal text in PHP

Tags: php, styles

I want to import some timestamps from a table and I want to write them diagonal under the graph. How can I do that?

here is my code, but not for the import data.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

$img   = imagecreate(100, 75);
$bg    = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

$roles = array('anoniem', 'ingelogd', 'leerling', 'docent', 'rector');
$left  = 0;
foreach ($roles as $role) {
  imagestring ($img, 2, 0, $left, $role, $black);
  $left+= 15;
}

$img2 = imagerotate($img, 45, $bg);
imagedestroy($img);

imagepng($img2);
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What have you tried? I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve

Comment: do you need css3 solution?

Comment: http://ciese.org/curriculum/weatherproj2/images/graph_bar_precip.gif  bun instead of months of the year i want some timestamp that are stored in a table of database. Does anyone know how to upload a picture here?

Comment: Shaunak Shukla, do you have a css solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) is used to write text to an image resource at any angle.  This isn't quite a drop-in replacement for `imagestring()` but it's not difficult to get working. Modifying your code gives me this:

```
$img   = imagecreate(100, 75);
$bg    = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 0);
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);

$roles = array('anoniem', 'ingelogd', 'leerling', 'docent', 'rector');
$left  = 10;
foreach ($roles as $role) {
  imagettftext($img, 10, 45, $left, 50, $black, 'arial.ttf', $role);
  $left+= 15;
}

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
```

And this seems to be what you want.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]